Unable to format my usb drive as it is showing key icon and error showing target busy
I have tried to format my usb using gparted and default disks app, however, encountered this particular error target is busy and also showing this key icon and not allowing to unmount the pendrive. How to fix this issue? Although I have successfully formatted another usb but it is not showing in my windows system. Kindly assist for Ubuntu Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.


flash media is a cheap consumable product and fails...  You've provided no Ubuntu product and release details for us to provide specific detail; you refer to a icon as if there is a link to attachment, but none was provided.  Your details don't rule out a hardware/media issue which software cannot correct anyway; but provides few specifics for us to help with too  (if device is busy; that's usually the result of user behavior/errors, so also check what you actually did; if you have another user/process actually using it preventing umount etc).

I have added the error screenshot and the ubuntu version. Please help.

The key icon means that it is mounted.  If nothing is using it, you should be able to right click on it and unmount it.
"device busy" means something is using it.  Like, programs are running that have open files on that device.   Maybe you have another window or application open that is using or viewing a file on that device?
Sometimes you can open a file manager window, find the device in the left pane and click the eject icon next to the device.  It may pop up the "volume busy" dialog with the "eject anyway" button.  You can try clicking on that, sometimes it works, but ultimately you will need to find out what is using it.
Use the command lsof with /media/deb... path in your gdisk unmount dialog (suggest using tab completion instead of typing it) should list what processes have the filesystem open.  Once you know what is holding it, you can find those apps and close them or kill them or tell them to release what they have open and then try again to eject or unmount it.
